# Unsupported clang availability platform: 'bridgeos'

Tags: ios, objective-sharpie, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm trying to bind Custom Native iOS Framework and getting this error in the 1st stage of sharpie bind -output bindings.
Below is the command and log when I hit the below command:

**sharpie bind --output=filename --namespace=namespacename --sdk=iphoneos11.4  /path/to/the/headerfile**

Logs:

System.Exception: Unsupported clang availability platform: 'bridgeos'
  at Sharpie.Bind.Attributes.AvailabilityBaseAttribute+d__6.MoveNext () [0x0037d] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Attributes/AvailabilityBaseAttribute.cs:192 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0006f] in <3fb92ec709f44a579da6a23087df403d>:0 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AvailabilityMassager.Massage (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.EntityDeclaration entity) [0x00092] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/AvailabilityMassager.cs:55 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AvailabilityMassager.VisitPropertyDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.PropertyDeclaration propertyDeclaration) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/AvailabilityMassager.cs:29 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.PropertyDeclaration.AcceptVisitor (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.IAstVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitChildren (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode node) [0x00010] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitTypeDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.AvailabilityMassager.VisitTypeDeclaration (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/AvailabilityMassager.cs:24 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.TypeDeclaration.AcceptVisitor (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.IAstVisitor visitor) [0x00000] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitChildren (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode node) [0x00010] in :0 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.DepthFirstAstVisitor.VisitSyntaxTree (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.SyntaxTree syntaxTree) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Sharpie.Bind.DocumentSyntaxTree.AcceptVisitor (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.IAstVisitor visitor) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/DocumentSyntaxTree.cs:37 
  at Sharpie.Bind.BindingMassager.Massage (ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.AstNode astNode, Sharpie.Bind.BindingTarget bindingTarget) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/BindingMassager.cs:103 
  at Sharpie.Bind.BindingFrontend.Bind (Clang.Ast.Decl decl) [0x000b5] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie.Bind/BindingFrontend.cs:61 
  at Sharpie.BindTool.HandleTranslationUnit (Clang.Ast.TranslationUnitDecl decl) [0x0018b] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/BindTool.cs:164 
  at Clang.Driver.HandleTranslationUnit (Clang.Ast.TranslationUnitDecl translationUnit) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Clang/Driver.cs:158 
  at Clang.Driver.HandleTranslationUnit (System.IntPtr translationUnit) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Clang/Driver.cs:148 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Clang.Driver:RunInternal (Clang.Driver,string[],string,Clang.Frontend.DiagnosticConsumer)
  at Clang.Driver.Run (System.String[] inputFiles, System.String[] clangArgs, Clang.Frontend.DiagnosticConsumer diagnosticConsumer) [0x00177] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Clang/Driver.cs:139 
  at Sharpie.ParseTool.Run () [0x005c8] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/ParseTool.cs:576 
  at Sharpie.BindTool.CoreRun () [0x00001] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/BindTool.cs:120 
  at Sharpie.BindTool.Run () [0x00026] in /Users/builder/vsts/_work/2/s/Sharpie/BindTool.cs:98

Below are the details of command : **sharpie  xcode -sdks**

sdk: appletvos11.4    arch: arm64
sdk: iphoneos11.4     arch: arm64   armv7
sdk: macosx10.13      arch: x86_64  i386
sdk: watchos4.3       arch: armv7k

Answer (score 3):

We experienced the exact same issue, and solved it by uninstalling Xcode 9.4(or 9.3 if that is what you have), downloading Xcode 9.2 from apple, installing it and rebooting. After this you can use sharpie with iphoneos11.2 (instead of 11.4 which sharpie does not support yet it seems).

I assume some breaking changes was introduced with xcode 9.2 and the latest swift-updates.

NB: This is just to generate the bindings, afterwards, when you have the structs and apidefs, you can upgrade to xcode 9.4 and compile as usual...